# AFrame - Error in loading marker on Worker 404

Tags: html, web, aframe

i´m having a problem trying to load my nft marke, that´s what i did:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>
    <body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
      <a-scene embedded arjs="trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam;debugUIEnabled: false;">
              
        <a-nft
        type="nft"
        url="nftmarkers/pinball"
        smooth="true"
        smoothCount="10"
        smoothTolerance=".01"
        smoothThreshold="5">
            <a-box position='0 0.5 0' ></a-box>
        </a-nft>
        <a-camera></a-camera>
      </a-scene>
     </body>
</html>
```

and that´s the error that it returns to me:

```
432abd3a-f330-4cc8-8c03-faa918143656:76 Error in loading marker on Worker 404
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my server sending the page as result and not the content. I fixed sending the web app to firebase.

Comment: Hi can you please explain what you mean by sending page as result ? im having same issue im using local apache server.